# How to reply to two users

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies

Suppose I wants to reply to two users in the comments. How to do that?

For example, in one of question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427958/how-to-print-bibliography-using-biblatex-just-as-enuemeration-using-keywords) I wants to reply to two different users namely [moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) and [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) saying that I have edited my question as they have suggested.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only reply to one person in one comment, so if you *need* to reply to two people, you need to use two separate comments. The question though is whether you need to reply at all: I'm not sure you do here.

Comment: Whether the users are notified when there is a edit in the question where they have commented??

Comment: @David No, not if it's not their question

Comment: @David My point really is that suggesting an edit doesn't necessarily _require_ a reply